# time limit exceeded for next palindrome

Tags: c

given a number, i was aked to find the next number which is a palindrome.Thisis the code i have writen.  my code works fine but the website I am working on says "time limit exceeded"...how do I correct this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


#define MAXLEN 50

void reverse (char s[]){

int c,i,j;

for (i=0,j=strlen(s)-1;i<j;i++,j--){
   c= s[i];
   s[i]=s[j];
   s[j]=c;
  }
}

void itoa (int n, char s[]) {

  int i;
  i = 0;
  do {
     s[i++] = n % 10 + '0'; 
     } while ((n /= 10) > 0); 
     s[i] = '\0';
     reverse(s);
}

  int main (void) {

  int t,j;
  scanf("%d",&t);

  for(j=0;j<t;j++){
     int k,c=1,i;
     char s[MAXLEN];
     scanf("%d",&k);
     int a= k+1;
     while (c!=0){
         itoa(a,s);
         int e=strlen(s)-1;
         for(i=0;i<(e+1)/2;i++){
             if (s[i]==s[e-i]){
                 c=0;
             }
             else{
                 c=1;
                 goto state;
             } 
         }
         state:a++;
    }

    printf("%s\n",s);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `j--` in the `for`-loop in `reverse`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a smarter way than brute force!

Here is an algorithm with time complexity log(N):

Read the number as a string.

Take the first half of the number. 
Make a palindrome by adding the first half reversed. (Consider the two cases: even/odd length of the original number)

If this palindrome is greater than the original number you are done.

If it is not: 
Take the first half of the number and add 1.

Make a palindrome by adding the first half reversed. (Again consider the two cases: even/odd length of the original number).

Done!

Comment: If the number is a string, wouldn't it be much faster to simply iterate the string from both ends and compare first against last, until the iterators meet?

Comment: but how do i increment the number if it were a string?

Comment: @al27 One way is to first convert it to an integer type, add 1 and then convert it back to a string.

Comment: @Lundin Indeed, that would be faster, but it wouldn't find the *next number that is a palindrome*.